# Using Gradle plugin from composite build in root project buildscript

Tags: android, gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I use Gradle Kotlin DSL and in my project I have separate `build-dependencies` gradle module which is included in `settings.gradle.kts` like so:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

includeBuild("build-dependencies")
```

This module contains empty plugin implementation and `Deps` object. Its `build.gradle.kts` below:

```
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    gradlePluginPortal()
}

plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
    `java-gradle-plugin`
}

gradlePlugin {
  plugins.register("com.example.dependencies") {
      id = "com.example.dependencies"
      implementationClass = "com.example.dependencies.DependenciesPlugin"
  }
}
```

Deps object:

```
object Deps {
  const val buildTools = "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1"
  // more dependencies
}
```

I want to use this `Deps` object in all modules by applying the plugin in `build.gradle.kts` files.

```
plugins {
  id("com.example.dependencies")
}
```

And it works fine, I can import and use `Deps` object.

But there is a problem when I want to use it in root projects `build.gradle.kts` and more precisely in buildscript like so:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    plugins {
        id("com.example.dependencies")
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath(com.example.dependencies.Deps.buildTools) // It doesn't work
    }
}
```

Is there any way to use a custom plugin inside buildscript like this or could you suggest something to replace this approach?

Comment: I have the same questions, did you resolved?

Comment: You should use a dependency catalog instead https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html.